# Passing configuration information to service factory

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have a MVC controller that calls a service(GlobalService) to perform operations , based on parameters passed , the GlobalService performs certain operations on its own repository as well as other Platform services that are created using a factory . If I want to pass certain config information like connection strings , and some UI paths to use for pictures etc  , to the IPlatform object created what is the best way to do this.

MVC Controller ---- > Gloabl Service ---- > IPlatformFactory.GetPlatform("platform1") --- > Platform1(string connString , string filePath)

Comment: Who (what object) owns the information?

Comment: The config information is owned by the MVC app

Comment: The global application class?

Comment: No , we can pass on this information to the Globalservice which can pass it on further from the MVC controller

Comment: Either you don't understand my question or I don't understand your answer. In terms of Object-oriented principles, which class is the owner of the configuration information? You first say "the MVC app" and then "the MVC controller". If you want to pass the information TO a class, you first have to determine FROM where you will pass it.

Comment: I am sorry , I might have confused you. The MVC Controller has config information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider adding parameters to `Platform` constructor, like it's done in [DbContext](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbcontext(v=vs.113).aspx)

```
public interface IPlatform 
{
    ...
}

public abstract class Platform : IPlatform 
{
    public Platform(string connString , string filePath) 
    {
      ...
    }
}


public sealed class Platform1 : Platform
{
    public Platform1(string connString, string filePath) : base(connString,  filePath) {}
}


public interface IPlatformFactory
{
    IPlatform GetPlatform(string code, string connString, string filePath);
}


public class PlatformFactory : IPlatformFactory
{

    public  IPlatform GetPlatform(string code, string connString, string filePath)
    {
        ...
        return new Platform1(connString,  filePath);
    }
}
```